# d3 create a custom compressed projection based on the mercator projection

Tags: d3.js

How do i create a custom projection based on the mercator projection which is compressed / scaled in the y-Axis ?
Right now I am using a TopoJson with this projection

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.rotate([96, 0])
.center([-.6, 38.7])
.scale(1070)
.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

Do I have to use the d3.geo.projectionMutator or d3.geo.stream ?

Comment: [Equirectangular](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3757119) (Plate Carrée) doesn't fulfill your needs?

Comment: no, i want to condense the y-coordinates so that the whole projection is e.g. 100 (or even 10) pixels in height.

Comment: have a look at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5663666